# Create multi column series asp:chart with custom objects list in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I would like to create a main overview chart with asp:chart control, like this:

[image]

Instead of Andrew, etc. it would be fiscal years (2009, 2010, 2011, etc.) and the products would be the 4 types of costs.
But how do I do this with a list of custom objects that are contstructed like this:

List< Cost_cost > listOfCosts

- Cost

  - Type (can be one of four types)
  - Amount (float)
  - Fiscal Year

Anybody got a link or tips on how to handle this?

Comment: Seriously, nobody? not even a link to a tut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, it's partialy hard coded, i.e., the types of costs but since it needs to be uploaded by the day after tomorrow, it'll do.

The following code of course is after I created Chart1, the mainlegend and area and some styling stuff:

```
//Set the amount of the four series to zero
float totalAmountHousing = 0, totalAmountPersonnel = 0, totalAmountServices = 0, totalAmountIT = 0;

//Create the four series per year
Series sr = new Series(); Series sr2 = new Series(); Series sr3 = new Series(); Series sr4 = new Series();

//Set the series to the same chart area
sr.ChartArea = "mainArea"; sr2.ChartArea = "mainArea"; sr3.ChartArea = "mainArea"; sr4.ChartArea = "mainArea";

//Set them to the same legend
sr.Legend = "mainLegend"; sr2.Legend = "mainLegend"; sr3.Legend = "mainLegend"; sr4.Legend = "mainLegend";

//Set the names of the 4 series
sr.Name = "Housing"; sr2.Name = "IT"; sr3.Name = "Services"; sr4.Name = "Personnel";

//Add the series to the chart
Chart1.Series.Add(sr); Chart1.Series.Add(sr2); Chart1.Series.Add(sr3); Chart1.Series.Add(sr4);

//Set drawing style to cylinder of the four costs
Chart1.Series["Housing"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
Chart1.Series["IT"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
Chart1.Series["Services"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
Chart1.Series["Personnel"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiscalYears.Count; i++) {

    //generate some point for the chart
    for (int j = 0; j < listOfCosts.Count; j++) {
        if ((listOfCosts[j].Type).ToLower() == "housing"    && listOfCosts[j].Cost_fiscalYear.Year == int.Parse(listOfFiscalYears[i].ToString())) totalAmountHousing += (float)listOfCosts[j].Amount;
        if ((listOfCosts[j].Type).ToLower() == "it"         && listOfCosts[j].Cost_fiscalYear.Year == int.Parse(listOfFiscalYears[i].ToString())) totalAmountIT += (float)listOfCosts[j].Amount;
        if ((listOfCosts[j].Type).ToLower() == "services"   && listOfCosts[j].Cost_fiscalYear.Year == int.Parse(listOfFiscalYears[i].ToString())) totalAmountServices += (float)listOfCosts[j].Amount;
        if ((listOfCosts[j].Type).ToLower() == "personnel"  && listOfCosts[j].Cost_fiscalYear.Year == int.Parse(listOfFiscalYears[i].ToString())) totalAmountPersonnel += (float)listOfCosts[j].Amount;
    }

    Chart1.Series["Housing"].Points.Add(totalAmountHousing);
    Chart1.Series["IT"].Points.Add(totalAmountIT);
    Chart1.Series["Services"].Points.Add(totalAmountServices);
    Chart1.Series["Personnel"].Points.Add(totalAmountPersonnel);
    Chart1.ChartAreas["mainArea"].AxisX.Interval = 1;

    //Add custom label to the X axis
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(i, i + 2, (listOfFiscalYears[i].ToString()), 0, LabelMarkStyle.None));

    //Reset the total cost after they have been added for the year
    totalAmountHousing = 0; totalAmountPersonnel = 0; totalAmountServices = 0; totalAmountIT = 0;
}
```